# parsing string in a log file in VBS

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging, vbscript, string-parsing

I have a windows system logs information to a text file. It is a bat file and records current date, time and result of a cygwin command to a text file.

Current text file is below.

```
Fri 05/16/2014 16:52:12.19 
JAVA_HOME = C:/jdk1.6.0_07
Checking rmi://ppm01:1094/KintanaServer
--> running (load: 343.0, mode: NORMAL)

Checking rmi://ppm02:1197/KintanaServer
--> running (load: 318.0, mode: NORMAL)

Checking rmi://ppm03:1297/KintanaServer
--> running (load: 0.0, mode: NORMAL)

------------------------------------------- 
Fri 05/16/2014 16:57:00.03 
JAVA_HOME = C:/jdk1.6.0_07
Checking rmi://ppm01:1094/KintanaServer
--> running (load: 334.0, mode: NORMAL)

Checking rmi://ppm02:1197/KintanaServer
--> running (load: 334.0, mode: NORMAL)

Checking rmi://ppm03:1297/KintanaServer
--> running (load: 0.0, mode: NORMAL)
```

**I want to change the text file to**

```
Fri 05/16/2014 16:52:12.19;ppm01;343
Fri 05/16/2014 16:52:12.19;ppm01;318
Fri 05/16/2014 16:52:12.19;ppm03;0
Fri 05/16/2014 16:57:00.03;ppm01;334
Fri 05/16/2014 16:57:00.03;ppm02;334 
Fri 05/16/2014 16:57:00.03;ppm02;0
```

How can I manipulate current text file with VBS to grap the information.

I could not change the command in cygwin also the result of the cygwin command. So what I only could do is changing the already written information.

Here my batch script:

```
@echo off
C:
cd C:\ppm\bin
echo %date% %time% >> userload_log.txt
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe kStatus.sh >> userload_log.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the file format change (batch file, not vbscript)

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set /a "mon=100", "tue=100", "wed=100", "thu=100", "fri=100", "sat=100", "sun=100"
    set /a "checking=200", "running=300"

    for /f "usebackq tokens=1-8 delims=>-/:. " %%a in ("userload_log.txt") do (
        set /a "id=%%a"
        if !id! equ 100 (
            set "ts=%%a %%b/%%c/%%d %%e:%%f:%%g.%%h;"
        ) else if !id! equ 200 (
            set "ppm=%%c;"
        ) else if !id! equ 300 (
            echo(!ts!!ppm!%%c
        )
    )
```

This code tokenizes the lines and uses the first token to determine the information that can be retrieved from it. The rest is saving the adecuated tokens in variables and each time a complete set is retrieved, echo to console the required record

For a VBS version

```
Option Explicit

Const ForReading = 1

Dim fso
    Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim inputFile
    Set inputFile = fso.OpenTextFile("userload_log.txt", ForReading )

Dim reDate, reChecking, reRunning    

Dim inputLine, id, ts, ppm

    Do While Not inputFile.AtEndOfStream
        inputLine = Trim(inputFile.ReadLine())
        If Len(inputLine) > 0 Then
            id = split(LCase(inputLine)," ")(0)
            Select Case id
                Case "mon","tue","wed","thu","fri","sat","sun"
                    ts = inputLine
                Case "checking"
                    ppm = Split(Mid(inputLine,16),":")(0)
                Case "-->"
                    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine ts & ";" & ppm & ";" & Split(Mid(inputLine,20),".")(0) 
            End Select
        End If
    Loop

    inputFile.Close()
```

Comment: @user3647076 Please don't forget to accept this answer by checking the hollow tick mark beside the vote count so that `MC ND` gets the credit.